# Looking for a Open Source SimpleSAML plugin for Alfresco

Tags: plugins

We have an Alfresco 5.1 community edition. Currently looking for a open source SAML plugin. If there is

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* - I don't know how this got migrated; they shouldn't have moved your question to a site where it's off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is community edition of the plugin. We were able to manage with a OAuth plugin which directly authenticates to Google.